# Am I allowed to work remotely for the company in my home country (The Netherlands) while studying in the US with an F-1 visa?

Tags: usa, study

Like the title says, is this permitted?

I currently work for a software company in the Netherlands and I'm aware that working is not permitted (except on-campus) with an F-1 visa, however is this also the case for remote work?

Comment: Welcome Jelle. While we are willing to answer your questions, this one about working while staying on a long term visa fits much better on our sister site for expats and will likely be closed to be moved there.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that there was an SE website for long-term travelling. I'll wait out the question transfer then.

Comment: I-20 isn't a visa or nonimmigrant status or class; it's a form that is required for someone to qualify for student status.  The visa itself will normally be an F-1 or M-1 visa, although I doubt this detail will change the answer.

Comment: Ah, you're right phoog. I-20 is indeed the form that I received, I'll update the question.